# Regular Expression: String contains substring with max length 15 and minimum 7 digits

Tags: python, regex, max

How to check if in a string exists a substring

- with maximum length of 15 characters
- which includes min 7 digits

My current regexp for python:

```
(?:\D*\d\D*)[\D\d]{7,15}


Examples:
1) aaaa1111111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [match]
2) 111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1111 [no match]
3) 111aaa1aaa111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [match]
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Do you just need a boolean result?

Comment: I use it in python 3.7

Comment: I do not think it makes sense to use regex for this, it is not quite meant for that. Just check the length of matches after you get all of them. And you need to use overlapping match search here to get all of the possible matches.

Comment: I don't see any other option because I have to query a SQL Database (Usging django ORM)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know your match left- and right-hand context, it is not quite feasible to write such a regex because you would have to list all possible length variations of the pattern.

Thus, if possible, extract all possibly overlapping matches with `re.findall(r'(?=(\d(?:\D*\d){6}))', s)` and then check if at least one match is 15 chars or less long.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zWX3jq):

```py
import re
l = ['aaaa1111111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', '111aaa1aaa111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', '111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1111']
for s in l:
    print(s)
    matches = re.findall(r'(?=(\d(?:\D*\d){6}))', s)
    if bool([x for x in matches if len(x) <= 15]):
        print("[matched]")
    else:
        print("[not matched]")
```

Output:

```
aaaa1111111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
[matched]
111aaa1aaa111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
[matched]
111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1111
[not matched]
```

Note: `(?=(\d(?:\D*\d){6}))` matches empty strings while capturing sequences of a digit followed with six occurrences of any zero or more non-digit chars followed with a digit, and `re.findall` returns just those substrings captured.

**Updated**

I generated strings of size 7 to 15 chars with at least 7 digits, and generated a pattern out of these thousands of strings. You may use it as is, see [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##7d3NTiJREAXgtTxFxw2QTEzM7EwmbnwLYEGgDST8pWGhybw7A8IIAg10Nw0NfCwcHFT03nNO1am6P6PPSWc4@D2ddvujYTQJorDUC/4EtXJz9nhePJqbj/KvoLz4/@fFV8W@vv2Y/8ByoxR9zN4lCp9aw/6o2wsrUbny@lJvZ/5Qq7frb43Xv/W35bPq/HncS6sXU33zxrdf4hfY9Svc6UDEDgVg3Dsw9kMDPggH4QCMncJxhHSACf2gH4Ah8YAPwgEYKX6Beru6fByXbQAI5aAcgCHlgA/CARhZUg71DdCgGYCRQDNkGECxCYo714jFKFwMBV9vn/Lvnn9vzDvOXvr6mKo@QQnkDfIGwFCkgA/CARiKFKBBMwBDkQIoFCkUKXIrUlhDQQNkDIAhYwAKGYOM4WDGoLqA/dh/p@wX9e9joi/L5XP8iVnm78j32PcXrH3d8t/0ywYEXOacOQcMawfgg3AAhrUDoEEzAEMnACjUApWIrB2gATIGwJAxAIWMQcZg7QD2Yz/2Wztgoq0duKm1A04cEGrZcsBgy4FCYi5fY8uxH/uxny1ny9nyS9lyfXJBVpAVZAVZQVaQzSfI8rBohmZ506wAcex@Rz8z6nP71Q6O185v@36Wcesz46STqZMJGPY/wwfhAAz7n0GDZgCGZVNAoaejBmn/Mw2QMQCGjAEoZAwyBgutsR/7sd8aMBNtcYr9z0ItW2482HIBGigk5mw59mM/9rPlJpotZ8vtfxZkBVnaK8iaaEHW/mc0QzP7n42@/c@n3//s5meWSQ8TMPQwgUKBhSHQw8R@7Md@5VUTre6jhynICrK0V5A10YKsHiaaoRma6WHqYRaoh2kHJrPELDFLzJIsTh7BLKEZmjFLRp9Z2jZLekp0nJLQcTp@1TpelEwcwG4TYKfRriL/icfN38Gfs/b8FFcKqk/bXWN3DWC4VxA@CAdguFcQNGgGYNjKCxSWzmgRuFeQBsgYAEPGABQyBhmDwz@wH/ux31J7E23tmHsFhVq23Hiw5QI0UEjM2XLsx37sZ8tNNFvOljuTU5AVZGmvIGuiBVnHzKAZmjmewOjbPe5eQZZJDxMw9DCBQoGFIdDDxH7sx37lVROt7qOHKcgKsrRXkDXRgqwgq4eJZmimh6mH6V5BZolZEtyZJRMti5NHMEtohmbMktF3ryAdp@OUhI7TcfcKAhiAuVcw472C6a8VVJm2rwYwtCzUs4FCH8u@GuzHfuzXxTbRyrLqNvbVCLKCLO0VZE20IGupGJqhmSUGOsA6wPbVMEvMkuDOLJloWRyzhGZohmbMErNkXw0dp@N03OjTcftqAMy@mqvdV@OmGjVpNWm5t5o0kyULU5NGMzRTyzD6rKaaNB2n43ScjqtJAxiAqUmfqSZthbQ0iw5Ls0RBaRaAAZg0K480q1B1LPRET/RMMnBGL370EqAu4Y/@8dn30cQZzia2pspAOKUYMOKAsR8a8EE4CAdgrI43t8IMNGgGYLgSAShs99Bv3XslgrWMNEDGABgyBqCQMcgYXKKE/diP/baHW4hrKdAlLlGy9l2oZcsBgy0HCom5fI0tx37sx3623ESz5e42FmQFWdoryJpoQdbRqGiGZmjmrBd7/Qtyt7HbJFgmPUzA0MMECgUWhkAPE/uxH/uVV020uo8epiAryNJeQdZEC7J6mGiGZmimh6mHWaQeph2YzBKzxCwxS7I4eQSzhGZoxiwZfWZp2yzpKdFxSkLH6bhLWgEMwNwCeeJLWjPdLagybV8NYGhZqGcDhT6WfTXYj/3Yr4ttopVl1W3sqxFkBVnaK8iaaEHWUjE0QzNLDHSAdYDtq2GWmCXBnVky0bI4ZgnN0AzNmCVmyb4aOk7H6bjRp@P21QCYfTVXu6/GTTVq0mrScm81aSZLFqYmjWZoppZh9FlNNWk6TsfpOB1XkwYwAFOTPlNN2gppaRYdlmaJgtIsAAMwaVYeaVah6ljoiZ7omWTgjF786CVAXcIf/eOzExxNbDWV84mdTwwYzicGCmsvnU8sV8B@7Lfy2kTrcamyOZ9YkBVkaa8ga6IFWdub0AzN0Mx6Lf165xMzS8yS4M4smWhZHLOEZmiGZswSs@QsCDpOx@m40afjNikCmF1QzidWk1aTlnurSZtoJksWpiaNZmimlsFqqknTcTpOSeg4HVeTBjA1aTVp5xNLs6RZ0iyjL80CMACTZjmfGD3REz2dT3yl5xOnP57YOirrqBQyrKMy0SpWcmbrqNAMzRSGjb51VHScjlMSOk7HNfgATAdBDdw6KmmWNEuaZfSlWQAGYNIs66jQEz3R0zqqm1hH5SQqnlXU5FnlLDwrgAGYpJhnRU/05FmNXkE9a/E6rMSUmJIDYnp9YnrqnNRs5ThbSVmV8f02Pv@/8bZaLVdL78MoGAfdQdB7KT2Mou5gUhlXSw/d9yD6eBqHzajVmf3H7LXli4@1fnPS6oTtxuPsy8LeOFx/bTCcBKvXp9N/).

The output is the same as above.